# How to define One-to-Zero-to-One relationship with constraint using Fluent API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I have two tables as following

```
public class Person {
[Key]
public int Id { get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

and

```
public class Office {
[key]
public int OfficeId {get; set;}
public string OfficeName { get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set;}
}
```

Now I want a relationship in the third table such as

```
[PersonHasOffice]
|  PersonId     | OfficeId   |
```

such that the user can have **only one or no** office.
When I try the following,relationship generated is many to many!

```
modelBuilder.Entities<Office>
.HasMany(e=>e.Persons)
.WithMany()
.Map(m=>m.ToTable("PersonHasOffice").MapLeftKey("OfficeId").MapRightKey("Id"));
```

How to get one-to-zero-to-one relationship on the Person side such that either a person has an office or none.

Comment: User and Person are same?

Comment: Yep. Sorry for the mistake. I’ve corrected it now.

Comment: Did you solve issue?

Comment: please see my comment to your proposed solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using extra mapping table, you can add a nullable column `OfficeId` as a foreign key in `Person` table.

```
public class Person 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

   [ForeignKey("OfficeId")]
   public virtual Office  Office  {get;set;}
   public int? Office Id {get;set;} = null;
}
```

Add this change to `Person` class, then run `Add-Migration <MigrationName>` and run `Update-Database` from Package Manager Console.

Comment: But this way, I'll have null entries in the table. I wanted to avoid that by using mapping table. Is there anyway in implementing it with mapping table. VS generates identical code for this mapping using _Database First_ approach, but somehow when I write it, the relationship is not same!